# Getting authentication delegation settings for an AD account from a non Domain controller with Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, kerberos-delegation

I have admin rights on a machine connected to AD. But I don't have rights on the Domain Controller.

With PowerShell is it possible to get all authentication delegation settings of an AD account from my admin machine? If possible how?

What I mean as delegation settings is the Delegation tab of the AD account, used for Kerberos authentication. Below is a snapshot of what I am referring about. Currently I could see few services to which the account can present delegated credentials, but not all since I cannot scroll down the list as it is greyed out.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell installed?

Comment: @T-Heron : Yes I have the ActiveDirectory module imported in my PS session.

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-ADObject -Filter {name -eq "yoursamaccountname"} -Properties msDS-AllowedToDelegateTo
```

Comment: I get the warning : 

PS F:\Documents> Import-Module ActiveDirectory
WARNING: Error initializing default drive: 'Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not
exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running.'.

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq "YourAccountSamName"} -Properties msDS-AllowedToDelegateTo | Select-Object -ExpandProperty msDS-AllowedToDelegateTo
```

It will list all services to which the account can present delegated credentials

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Neroon did not work for me unfortunately, but I come up with a solution for AD user that works in case anyone else is looking for it:

```
Get-ADUser -filter { SamAccountName -eq "YouAccountSamName" } -Properties TrustedForDelegation | Select SamAccountName, TrustedForDelegation | FT -A
```

For multiple users:

```
$users = @('user1', 'user2')
$users | ForEach {Get-ADUser -filter { SamAccountName -eq $_ } -Properties TrustedForDelegation} | Select SamAccountName, TrustedForDelegation | sort -property SamAccountName | FT -A
```